# How to get equivalent user input in Android on Unity's Roll-a-Ball tutorial?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I was following this Unity tutorial:

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial/moving-player?playlist=17141

While the ball's speed is fine for a standalone (Windows) platform, the user input on rolling the ball is extremely fast when using Android.

This is the standalone Windows user input, which works fine and serves as my model for the Android:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets all user input from a standalone device.
/// </summary>
private void GetInput_PC()
{ 
    // Update the movement vector
    m_movementVector.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    m_movementVector.y = 0.0f;
    m_movementVector.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    // Add force to the player's rigid body.
    m_rigidBody.AddForce(m_movementVector * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Now what the tutorial doesn't cover is how to make this effective on mobile devices. This is my attempt:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets all user input from an Android device.
/// </summary>
private void GetInput_Android()
{
    // Update the movement vector
    m_movementVector.x = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    m_movementVector.y = 0.0f;
    m_movementVector.z = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

    // Get the touch count
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        // Update the movement vector
        m_movementVector.x += Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.x;
        m_movementVector.y = 0.0f;
        m_movementVector.z += Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.y; 

        // Add force to the player's rigid body.
        m_rigidBody.AddForce(m_movementVector * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    } 
}
```

However, there are a few problems:

1) The ball moves much faster than the standalone implementation.

2) The father your move your thumb, the faster the ball goes.

Overall, how can this Android code be rearranged to have an equivalent speed with the standalone PC version?

Added full script:

```
#region Using Clauses
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
#endregion

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    private Rigidbody m_rigidBody;
    private Vector3 m_movementVector = new Vector3();
    public float Speed;

    /// <summary>
    /// Called after initialization.
    /// </summary>
    private void Start()
    {
        m_rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called before rending a frame.
    /// </summary>
    private void Update()
    { 
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called before performing any physics calculations.
    /// </summary>
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR || UNITY_STANDALONE
            GetInput_PC(); 
        #elif UNITY_ANDROID
            GetInput_Android();
        #endif
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all user input from a standalone device.
    /// </summary>
    private void GetInput_PC()
    { 
        // Update the movement vector
        m_movementVector.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        m_movementVector.y = 0.0f;
        m_movementVector.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        // Add force to the player's rigid body.
        m_rigidBody.AddForce(m_movementVector * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all user input from an Android device.
    /// </summary>
    private void GetInput_Android()
    {
        // Update the movement vector
        m_movementVector.x = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        m_movementVector.y = 0.0f;
        m_movementVector.z = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        // Get the touch count
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            // Update the movement vector
            m_movementVector.x += Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.x;
            m_movementVector.y = 0.0f;
            m_movementVector.z += Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.y; 

            // Add force to the player's rigid body.
            m_rigidBody.AddForce(m_movementVector * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
        } 
    }
}
```

A second attempt, but still too fast when the thumb moves quickly.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets all user input from an Android device.
/// </summary>
private void GetInput_Android()
{ 
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        Vector3 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(touchDeltaPosition.x, 0.0f, touchDeltaPosition.y);
        m_rigidBody.AddForce(movement * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Edit: Attempted the first answer. While normalizing works, I am still having the same problem with different speeds occurring between Android and Windows. Trying the suggested CrossPlatformInput doesn't work for Android according to several pages and personal attempts. Still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you are using `+=`  instead of `=` for the code in the `GetInput_Android` function. Even though it's not the problem because you are overriding the values with `Input.GetAxis` in the beginning of the function, it could be when you remove `Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")` and `Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")` that's inside the `GetInput_Android` function.

The problem is that your `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")` and `Input.GetAxis("Vertical")` are returning values between `0` and `1` on the Editor and standalone builds but `Input.touches.deltaPosition.x` and `Input.touches.deltaPosition.y` are returning values based on the speed of the finger over the screen. Sometimes, this value can be up to `42` an that's a huge number.

You have to normalize it before using it:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    //Update the movement vector
    m_movementVector.x = Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.x;
    m_movementVector.y = 0.0f;
    m_movementVector.z = Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.y;

    //NORMALIZE VECTOR
    m_movementVector.Normalize();

    // Add force to the player's rigid body.
    m_rigidBody.AddForce(m_movementVector * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

or use the normalized property of the `Vector3` struct:

```
//Update the movement vector
m_movementVector.x = Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.normalized.x;
m_movementVector.y = 0.0f;
m_movementVector.z = Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.normalized.y;
```

---

While this should fix the problem, this is not the best way to implement this. The best way is to make a virtual joystick with the `OnBeginDrag` `OnDrag` and the `OnEndDrag` functions and this will work on any platform. You can also use already made one "`CrossPlatformInputManager`" on the [Assetstore](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/asset-packs/standard-assets-32351) to save yourself time:

```
m_movementVector.x = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal") ;
m_movementVector.z = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical");
```

Comment: Normalizing seems to be giving a more satisfying effect. The ball seems a little slow comparing to the Windows version still.

Comment: Read the ending part of the answer where I said even this should fix the speeding problem, it's not the best way to do it. You have to use different API for that. Did you read that part?

Comment: You wrote something?

Comment: I'm not sure when you last used that asset, but it is out of date. I can't even compile it. As someone stated in the reviews: "Someone needs to update or clean up this pack or make one suitable for the latest versions of the engine. Many of the assets found here use deprecated features and ancient code."

Comment: @Bob You only need to import "Cross Platform Input" from that Asset. Ignore the rest.

Comment: While I got CrossPlatformInputManager to work for Windows, it does not seem to do anything with the code provided above for Android using CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal") and CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical"); The ball stands still.

Comment: Android uses Touch, so I don't know why the answer is to use GetAxis here. I did a test anyway to see if Axis exists during an Android runtime and it does not.

Comment: Apparently CrossPlatformInput isn't cross platform: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1365300/crossplatforminputmanager-doesnt-work-on-android.html 
Sorry, I can't accept this answer, though it's leading in the right direction.